# Is this a valid proof using Pigeon Hole Principle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

[Pigeon Hole Question from last semester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47a2i.jpg)
S = { 1, 2, 3, . . . 100 }

examples of sets that add to 3: {1 , 2}
examples of sets that add to 4: {1 , 3}
examples of sets that add to 5: {3 , 2}, {4 , 1}
examples of sets that add to 6: {4 , 2}, {5 , 1}
examples of sets that add to 7: {4 , 3}, {5 , 2}, {6 , 1}
examples of sets that add to 8: {2 , 6}, {5 , 3}, {7 , 1}
examples of sets that add to 9: {1 , 8}, {2 , 7}, {5 , 4}, {3 , 6}

There are 10 pigeons and 9 holes. Therefore by PHP there are 2 elements in a subset.
From the above eamples we see that there exists two or more subsets that can be made
which add to the same number and as the sum increases so does the possible subsets.

Comment: May I suggest to actually *write* the question text here?

Comment: I don't see any connection between your examples and the statement about $10$ pigeons and $9$ holes.

Answer (score 1):

No need for PHP. Just note that
$$1+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+12 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11$$

Comment: Or to give the general principle in pictures: $$\text{same sum:}\\\color{red}\bullet\quad\bullet\bullet\ldots\bullet\bullet\quad\color{red}\bullet\\\color{red}\bullet\bullet\bullet\ldots\bullet\bullet\;\color{red}\bullet$$

Answer (score 1):

The subsets of size $10$ have a sum that ranges from $55$ to $955$, and presumably all sums are possible, hence $901$ distinct values.

But there are $\displaystyle\binom{100}{10}$ ways to form the sums, which is a much larger number.